# NX Console in VS Code is after restarting my laptop empty

Tags: visual-studio-code

I use the NX console in my VS Code and till I restarted my laptop just 10 minutes ago, all worked fine. But now the nx console is empty and I can't do anything. I don't know what I can do to fix this.

Do anyone have an idea, how to fix it?

Here is an image:
[image]

I've searched for ways to solve it, but nothing has worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can revert the version from v18.10.0 to v18.9.0 on the extension's page and that solves the problem for now(it works fine for me).

Extensions page change version:

[image: extensions page change version]

See also [this GitHub repo](https://github.com/nrwl/nx-console/issues/1925).